# Clue Web #1 - Let's start

Tags: word

This may not be perfect and I have no idea how it should be tagged to be honest but...  Here's an idea for a word puzzle.  A clue web!

[image]

You get 4 clues for each of the outer labels (A1, A2, etc.) on the web.

You solve those clues to fill in the outer labels with the answers.

You then use those answers as clues to solve the inner web (A, B, C, D).

And finally, you use those answers as clues to solve the centre answer (X).

Once you have all of the answers you submit them as:

A1, Pie

A2, Cake

A3, Come

A3, Go

A, Easy

etc.

If you struggle with any of the labels in the web, then try leaving it 'til last.  If you can't get D, you may still be able to get 'X' and then you'll have one more clue to help you.

Get the idea?

Good!  Me either...

Here are the clues to each outer label!

A1, Mat, Field, Church, Trap

A2, Chew, 32, Head, Chance

A3, Pig, Bones, Thick, Sheep

A4, Kin, Dirt, Sack, Power

B1, Sick, Dead, Out, Over

B2, Pot, Pocket, Plate, Shot

B3, In, Out, Run, Away

B4, Star, Tale, Go, Eye

C1, Pure, Lie, Flag, Fish

C2, Knuckles, Top, Bold, Tacks

C3, Cheap, Treat, Miss, Turn

C4, Blow, Luck, Ball, Case

(SORRY! SORRY! SORRY!)

<s>D1, April, Summer, Head, Cold</s>

D2, Rubbed, Plug, Deal, Red

D3, Pot, Bed, Corn, May

D4, Garden, Shed, Belt, Box

Well done to the puzzlers that got D but unfortunately I may have had too many of my ideas scrawled on the same page because that was for another of these puzzles!  The correct D below...

D1, Choice, World, Feet, Lady

D2, Sad,  Over, Balancing, Out

D3, Fox, Run, Fall, Shine

D4, Way, Atomic, Assembly, Marine

(Again! SORRY! SORRY! SORRY!)

Good luck! :)

Comment: Are any of the answers heterographs, or should I ignore such possibilities?

Comment: @jonathanAllan I don't think they are.  I had to google it though so...  um...  Still probably not though!

Comment: Most of the clues often appear with or form compound words with their answer or they appear together in expressions or idioms so if I came up with clues for 'sick' I might have sea (seasick) or 'chip' (sick as a chip) and so on

Comment: It's not a bad puzzle. Reminiscent of the iPad game where there are four pictures and you have to create the common theme from a letter set.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A1, Mat, Field, Church, Trap

> **Mouse** (mouse mat, field mouse, poor as a church mouse, mouse trap)

A2, Chew, 32, Head, Chance

> **Fat** (chew the fat, FAT32 [file system], fat head, fat chance)

A3, Pig, Bones, Thick, Sheep

> **Skin** (pigskin [rugby], all skin and bones, thick skin, sheepskin)

A4, Kin, Dirt, Sack, Power

> **Nap** (napkin, dirt nap, (k)napsack, power nap) - Partial credit Anthony Grist

**A**

> **Cat** (play cat and mouse, fat cat, catskin [fairy tale], cat nap)

B1, Sick, Dead, Out, Over

> Sea (seasick, Dead Sea, put out to sea, oversea)
>  **Tired** (tired sick, dead tired, tired out, over tired)

B2, Pot, Pocket, Plate, Shot

> **Hot** (hotpot, hot-pocket, hotplate, hotshot)

B3, In, Out, Run, Away

> **Eat** (eat in, eat out, eat on the run, eats away at*) * - credit Brent Hackers (the OP!!)

B4, Star, Tale, Go, Eye

> **Fish** (starfish, Fish Tale [film], go fish! [game], fish eye [camera lens])

**B**

> **Dog** (dog tired, hot-dog, a dog-eat-dog world, dogfish)

C1, Pure, Lie, Flag, Fish

> **White** (pure white, white lie, white flag, whitefish)

C2, Knuckles, Top, Bold, Tacks

> **Brass** (brass knuckles, top brass, bold as brass, brass tacks)

C3, Cheap, Treat, Miss, Turn

> **Trick** (cheap trick, trick or treat, miss a trick, turn a trick)

C4, Blow, Luck, Ball, Case

> Out (blow out, luck out, out ball [tennis], case out)
>  **Hard** (blowhard, hard luck, play hard ball, hard-case) - credit Radoslav Hristov

**C**

> **Hat** (white hat [well-meaning hacker], brass hat [high ranking officer], hat-trick[soccer/cricket], hard-hat [worn by a construction worker for example]

D1, Choice, World, Feet, Lady

> **First** (first choice, first world, feet first, first lady) - partial credit Sid

D2, Sad, Over, Balancing, Out

> **Act** (sad-act, over-act, balancing act, act out)

D3, Fox, Run, Fall, Shine

> **Out** (out-fox, outrun, fall out, out shine)

D4, Way, Atomic, Assembly, Marine

> **Sub** (subway, subatomic, sub-assembly, submarine) - credit Verence

**D**

> **Class** (first-class, class act, out-class, subclass [OO programming])

---

Previous category D...

D1, April, Summer, Head, Cold

> **Shower** (April showers, summer shower, shower head, cold shower)

D2, Rubbed, Plug, Deal, Red

> **Raw** (rubbed raw, raw(l) plug, raw deal, red raw)

D3, Pot, Bed, Corn, May

> **Flower** (flower pot, flower bed, cornflower [the flower, not the flour], Mayflower [the ship])

D4, Garden, Shed, Belt, Box

> **Tool** (garden tool, tool shed, tool belt tool box)

**D**

> **Power** (power shower, raw power, flower power, power tool)

---

**X**

> **Top** (top cat, top dog, top hat, top class) - also works with previous category D with "power top".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; for further discussion on this answer, the conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43468/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-allan-clue-web-1-lets-start).

Answer (score 2):

Some guesses:

A1:

> Mouse

A2:

> Teeth

A3:

> Skin

B2:

> Gold

D1:

> Spring

D4:

> Tool

Answer (score 1):

Some more guesses:

A4:

> Hit

B1:

> Sea

B3:

> Head

C1:

> White

C2:

> Down

C3:

> Trick

C4:

> Hard

And even more blind guesses:

A:

> Hole

B:

> Eagle

Comment: I think your C4 is right and mine is wrong...