# Clue Web #2 - A Barrel of Fun

Tags: word

[Tried one of these yeserday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40018/clue-web-1-lets-start) and it went pretty well (for the most part) so here's another clue web!

[image: Clue Web]

How it works:

You get 4 clues for each of the outer labels (A1, A2, etc.) on the web.

You solve those clues to fill in the outer labels with the answers.

You then use those answers as clues to solve the inner web (A, B, C, D).

And finally, you use those answers as clues to solve the centre answer (X).

Once you have all of the answers you submit them as:

A1, Pie

A2, Cake

A3, Come

A3, Go

A, Easy

etc.

If you struggle with any of the labels in the web, then try leaving it 'til last. If you can't get D, you may still be able to get 'X' and then you'll have one more clue to help you.

Here are the clues to each outer label!

A1, Bank, Sweet, Bed, On

A2, Light, Fish, Super, Chart

A3, Flower, Head, Bug, Water

A4, Hat, Swallow, Knocks, Up

B1, Maker, Strike, Perfect, Stick

B2, Fun, Riot, Rampant, Ragged

B3, Over, Down, Free, Flat

B4, Mouth, Phone, Cookie, Street

C1, Fit, Old, Crow, Foot

C2, Brass, Tip, Tail, Notch

C3, Hound, Hair, Area, Matter

C4, Pound, Effect, Wave, Board

D1, Sell, Mine, Paid, Writer

D2, Fine, Class, Work, State

D3, Desk, Seat, Stuff, Rod

D4, Back, Nerve, Grudge, Breath

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing C1 only...

A1, Bank, Sweet, Bed, On

> **Roll** (bankroll, sweetroll, bedroll, roll-on [deodorant] or to roll on Friday / roll on 5pm...)

A2, Light, Fish, Super, Chart

> **Star** (starlight, starfish, superstar, star-chart)

A3, Flower, Head, Bug, Water

> **Bed** (flowerbed, bed-head, bedbug, waterbed)

A4, Hat, Swallow, Knocks, Up

> **Hard** (hard hat, hard to swallow, school of hard knocks, to be hard up)

**A**

> **Rock** (rock and roll, rock star, bedrock, hard rock)

B1, Maker, Strike, Perfect, Stick

> **Match** (match maker, strike a match, a perfect match, matchstick)

B2, Fun, Riot, Rampant, Ragged

> **Run** (fun-run, to run riot, to run rampant, to run ragged)

B3, Over, Down, Free, Flat

> **Fall** (fall over yourself to..., downfall, free-fall, to fall flat on your face)

B4, Mouth, Phone, Cookie, Street

> **Smart** (smart-mouth, smartphone, a smart cookie, to be street-smart)

**B**

> **Out** (outmatch, outrun, fallout, outsmart)

C1, Fit, Old, Crow, Foot

> **Bill** (to fit the bill, the old bill, crow-bill, to foot the bill) - credit M Oehm (I didn't know of a crow-bill)

C2, Brass, Tip, Tail, Notch

> **Top** (top brass, tiptop, top and tail, top-notch)

C3, Hound, Hair, Area, Matter

> **Grey** (greyhound, grey hair, a grey area, grey matter)

C4, Pound, Effect, Wave, Board

> **Sound** (sound as a pound, sound-effect, sound wave, soundboard)

**C**

> **Dollar** (dollar bill, top-dollar, the grey dollar, sound as a dollar)

D1, Sell, Mine, Paid, Writer

> **Under** (undersell, undermine, underpaid, underwriter)

D2, Fine, Class, Work, State

> **Art** (fine-art, art class, artwork, state of the art)

D3, Desk, Seat, Stuff, Rod

> **Hot** (hot-desk, hot-seat, hot stuff, hotrod)

D4, Back, Nerve, Grudge, Breath

> **Hold** (don't hold back, hold your nerve, hold a grudge, hold your breath)

**D**

> **Line** (underline, line art, hotline, please hold the line)

**X**

> **Bottom** (hit rock bottom, to bottom out, bet your bottom dollar, the bottom line)
>  - which is an antonym of the  answer to clue web #1!

Comment: Well done Jonathan. +1. You got it.  C1 though...  Think unwanted mail.

Comment: And A4... I think you meant hard up rather than knock up?  And A3 waterbed rather than watrrbug... :)

Comment: And water bed instead of waterbug. `:)` But thanks for including the detailed explanations.

Comment: Oh, and couldn't C1 be "bill"? It fits the bill, I think. (Old Bill, crow-bill, foot the bill and dollar bill.)

Comment: @MOehm Nice one, didn't know the crow...

Answer (score 4):

Some guesses:

A1, Bank, Sweet, Bed, On

> roll (credit to shree.pat18)

A2, Light, Fish, Super, Chart

> star (credit to shree.pat18)

A3, Flower, Head, Bug, Water

> bed

A4, Hat, Swallow, Knocks, Up

> hard

B1, Maker, Strike, Perfect, Stick

> match

B2, Fun, Riot, Rampant, Ragged

> run

B3, Over, Down, Free, Flat

> run

B4, Mouth, Phone, Cookie, Street

> smart

C1, Fit, Old, Crow, Foot

> bird

C2, Brass, Tip, Tail, Notch

> top

C3, Hound, Hair, Area, Matter

> grey

C4, Pound, Effect, Wave, Board

D1, Sell, Mine, Paid, Writer

> under (somebody suggested it and then deleted their comment - credit goes to them)

D2, Fine, Class, Work, State

> art

D3, Desk, Seat, Stuff, Rod

> hot

D4, Back, Nerve, Grudge, Breath

> hold

A:

> rock  (credit goes to shree.pat18)

B:

> out

D:

> work

Comment: @BrentHackers So, how many of them are correct?

Comment: @Sid 13 so far.

Comment: Which are incorrect?? I would work on those

Comment: Well B2 and B3 aren't both 'Run' and C1 isn't the correct answer.

Comment: I don't think that D is "work", because it is one of the clues to D2.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

a1

> roll

a2

> star

a3

> bed

a4

> hard

b1

> match

b2

> act?

b3

> fall

b4

c1

c2

> top

c3

> grey

c4

> sound

d1

d2

d3

> <del>top?</del> hot based on Radoslav's answer

d4

> hold

a

> rock

b

> out (guessing - match and fall lead to outmatch and fallout)

c

d

> house (guessing - hold and hot lead to hothouse and household)

x

Comment: Well done on getting all of A +1 :)

Comment: @shree.pat18  Yep, I also think A is correct.

Comment: 16 correct answers so far

Comment: D isn't 'House' and B2 isn't 'Act'